# PyCharm type hinting for class/instance variables

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

I have been trying this:

```
class Symbol:
    name: str
    board: str
    sector: str
```

for type hinting of class/instance variables.

I do not get any errors, but PyCharm does not give me any warning when I violate the hinting, for example setting

```
self.name = 123
```

Yet, PyCharm otherwise gives me warnings, when I violate hinting of method signatures such as

```
def __init__(self, filename: str):
```

when I try to call the constructer and set filename to anything that is not str.

Is it possible to get PyCharm to give warnings over type hinting for class/instance variables?

Comment: Have you tried making it into a [property](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property) ? You can then type hint on the getter method maybe.

Comment: This is maybe a pycharm bug -- according to [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations), that code shouldn't typecheck. (Perhaps what Pycharm is doing is observing that your 'name' is currently a class variable, but 'self.name' is setting an instance variable, so ended up giving the two different 'name' attributes different types? IMO this is a reasonable thing to do; it just conflicts with the new conventions defined in PEP 526.) I'd perhaps try opening a bug report on Pycharm's issue tracker?

Comment: I believe you're looking for this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-24832 & https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27427

Comment: I think [PY-36889](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36889) is the bug most specifically applicable here.